# Energy Detection Sensitivity Comparison

Tags: fft, signal-detection, spectrogram

In the area of broadband spectrum sensing, there are multiple methods used to detect energy. Two common methods are:

1. Energy detection in the time domain ([matlab example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/energy-detection-in-time-domain.html))
2. [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) (often defined by a time and frequency resolution [Fs/NFFT], overlap percentage, and number of noncoherent averages [NAVG])

When doing energy detection in the time domain, a [polyphase channelizer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/channelizer.html) is often used make smaller subchannels of a large chunk of spectrum.

Questions:

1. How do you compare the sensitivity (ie probability of detection) between the two methods?
2. Is it accurate to say that the difference between the detection SNRs would be: $$ \Delta \text{SNR} = 10\log_{10}(\Delta f_1 / \Delta f_2) + 10\log_{10}\sqrt {N_{AVG}}$$ where $$ \Delta f = 1/F_s $$ for option 1 and $$ \Delta f = F_s/N_\text{FFT}  $$ for option 2?

Comment: 1. by modelling or simulating signals of different powers and deriving or measuring least reliable detection (you'll need to define a least probability of detection).

Comment: 2. no, since that depends on your signal model.